# Не удается загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#

Написал библиотеку классов на с#(ну как написал, скопировал по гайдику).
Подключил через "Add/Reference" к другому проекту, в котором требовалась данная либа.
Потом просто закинул в папку с проектом.
Никак не видит его и не хочет видеть.
Вроде проблема частая, но пути решения я так и не нашёл.
Кто подскажет, что можно сделать? Или что я возможно сделал не так? Потому что пока плохо разбираюсь в этом. Спасибо.

Comment: Проверьте версии `.NET` фреймворков. Из более старой версии нельзя использовать более новые dll-ки. И проверьте битность (х86, х64, AnyCPU) библиотеки и проекта.

Comment: Вы добавляли ссылку на dll или на проект с solution'е?

Comment: @VladD добавлял ссылку на dll

Comment: @fffffdffd: А вы поставили в свойствах ссылки CopyLocal = true?

Comment: @VladD да, стоит

Comment: нужно было сначала "закинуть", а потом подключать. проверьте путь к подключаемой сборке